# Как сбросить пароль администратора сайта?

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

Что-бы зайти в админ панел сайта Доступ к phpmyadmin имеется. Пробовал через базу ставить другой пароль в md5 бесполезно, пробовал создавать нового пользователя бесполезно. Руки опускаются.
CMS InstantCMS 2.8.0

Comment: уточните свой вопрос

Comment: У нас тоже, потому что из вопроса ничего не понятно. Какая cms?

Comment: @KAGGDesign InstantCMS 2.8.0

Answer (score 1):

Советуют следующее

"самый простой способ указать админу в базе новый email и сменить пароль."

http://www.instantcms.ru/forum/thread14096-1.html

Comment: Спасибо, сделаем